# Trouble with Python on Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am having trouble with the python on VS 2015. The print command is treated like a function call(I need to use parentheses) and raw_input won't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show what is the error of raw_input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem with the print command, this could be the python version being used. Most probably is version 3.X. You can change that adding a virtual environment to your project and selecting a 2.X version (that should be installed on your machine).

Comment: Also `raw_input` isn't present in Python 3 so that would suggest you are correct.

Comment: Yes, it's true, Duncan. I did forget of that, as I don't use raw_input often.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were so helpful!